# Facebook Opengraph for TV app posting shows that users are going to watch in the future

Tags: ios5, facebook-opengraph

We have a TV guide app that allows users to have actions to set alerts, add to calendar, watch, favorite and rate a TV show or film from normal linear TV and are using Facebook Opengraph to automatically share these with friend.

We have looked at using the built-in object types video.movie, video.episode and video.tv_show however as the user is quite often going to create an action like alert for a show in the future we would like to put the channel and show start time in the timeline. Unfortunately, we can't add custom properties for in-built types.

What would be best practice for this kind of Facebook Opengraph implementation?